# Connection string in app.config in a class library

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0

I am creating solution and inside I have three projects:

1. A WCF Service Library Project
2. A DataAccess Project (Class Library)
3. A Web site for hosting WCF service

The implementation of the service is on the project # 1, but in order to access the DataBase I use a second project that implements the data access using a class library project.

That problem is in order to get data access I need to configure a connection string, but that connection string must be configurable in a production environment, I meant in production I am going to deploy the site, which is a very simple project that contains only a reference WCF Service Library Project then a guy from database department will configure the connection string.

In development I have an app.config on the data access project but when I do the release that app.config is embedded on the dll.

Any ideas how can we achieve our purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection string in your app.config (data layer) is not embedded in the dll.

If you look in the app.config file in your data layer project, you will probably have a connectionStrings section. you need to put the connectionStrings in the web.config of your WCF service website.

This can be configured in your production environment.

Comment: I put the connectionstring on the web.config of the site but it doesn't work...I dont kwon if may be its the way I'm calling the app.config form the datalayer...here it's the app.config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WIW.DataAccess.Properties.Settings.WIWBancolombiaCS"
      connectionString="Data Source=HERMES;User Id=sa;Password=developer;Initial Catalog=WIWBancol17DEV;Integrated

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WIW.DataAccess.Properties.Settings.WIWBancolombiaCS"
      connectionString="Data Source=HERMES;User Id=sa;Password=developer;Initial Catalog=WIWBancol17DEV;Integrated Security=False" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: And I am calling the app.config this way ->

string conn = Properties.Settings.Default.WIWBancolombiaCS;

Answer (score 4):

The connection string must be in the application configuration file of the executing assembly.  This means that you can provided the configuration file for your assembly along with the assembly itself but anyone who wants to use your assembly must update their configuration file to include the values that your assembly relies on.

Comment: But the problem is when I compile the project the result is only a dll, no app.config is there I assume taht the app.config is embedded, how can I tell Visual Studio not to embedded th file?

Answer (score 1):

I had a mistake, I was using a different name on the web.config of the WCF site, I just copy the the exact part of the app.config to the web.config and its working now.

Thanks for your help