# App.config problem

Tags: c#

i am having a classlibrary with app1.config and also a windows application with app2.config;i am adding the reference of classlibrary in windows application as well as app1.config.is it possible if i call the method class lib it will go to app1.config otherwise it will use  app2.config;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using app.config with a class library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690313/using-app-config-with-a-class-library) and a great many other SO questions - please **SEARCH** first before posting the gazillionth repeat of the same question!

Comment: Or duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277635/reading-an-app-config-in-class-library

Comment: Or duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548726/connection-string-in-app-config-in-a-class-library or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946614/why-is-this-class-library-dll-not-getting-information-from-app-config

Comment: if u all think u r very intelligent  then y u r not giving the answer and i think u need the check the all previous answers they are not well explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can achieve is to have two separate configuration files, then have the code of one method read the "main" config file (using the ordinary `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting[""]` code) and other method read the configuration file of the class library using such code:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(dllFilePath);
KeyValueConfigurationElement element = config.AppSettings.Settings[appSettingKey];
string value = element.Value;
```

This will read application setting from the config file of DLL sitting in the location of `dllFilePath`.

You can also have separate section for the class library in the "main" configuration file if relevant I can give sample as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using the default ConfigurationManager process to access a configuration file it goes for the file that is configured for the application, there is no way to differentiate between a class library and an application's config.

For example if you have a windows/WPF app that is called MyWonderfulApp.exe, the only config file that will be used is MyWonderfulApp.exe.config.  Therefore all settings are in that file.  Web applications ONLY use the web.config file.